# Why can't I use this approach to calculate the cardinality of a Cartesian product?

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory

I know there's an equation saying that the cardinality of a Cartesian product for two sets, $A$ and $B$, is equal to the product of their respective cardinalities, $|A|$ and $|B|$.

I'm trying to extend my knowledge of combinatorics to calculate the cardinality of, say, $\{1, 2, 3, 4\}^2$, but my reasoning doesn't seem to work. Here's how I was thinking:

- $\{1, 2, 3, 4\}$ is the set of all unique pairs $(a, b)$ such that both $a$ and $b$ are in the given set
- There are ${4 \choose 2} = 6$ ways to choose $2$ of the $4$ given elements to serve as our $a$ and $b$
- Once we choose two elements, there are $2! = 2$ ways to permute $a$ and $b$ with each other
- Thus, I supposed that there are $2 \cdot 6 = 12$ such pairs $(a, b)$
- If there are $12$ pairs, then I was thinking the cardinality of the set of pairs would be $12$

Could someone please help me understand the flaw in my reasoning?

Comment: There are $ \binom {4}{2}=6 $  unordered pairs of unequal members of $S=\{1,2,3,4\}$ so there are $12$ ordered pairs $(a,b)\in S\times S$ for which $a\ne b.$  But there are also $4$ other ordered pairs in $S\times S,$ which are $(1,1),(2,2),(3,3),(4,4).$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint - Do you count the element $(1,1)$ with your thought process?

Comment: Oh, I see the flaw in my reasoning now. So if we draw two empty boxes representing the possible digits $a$ and $b$, then there are $4 \choose 1$ ways to pick $a$ from $\{1, 2, 3, 4\}$ for the first box and $4 \choose 1$ ways to pick $b$ from $\{1, 2, 3, 4\}$ for the second box. Thus, there are $4 \cdot 4 = 16$ such pairs. Thank you! :)

Comment: @AleksandrH sounds like a good explaination to me!

Comment: I'll go ahead and accept your answer once the timer is up. Thanks again!